# Flexbox with percentage width on firefox not working

Tags: css, css-float, tablelayout, flexbox

I tried to archive a simple sidebar | content visually with normal floats and then I used the classic technique for equal height columns with (`margin-bottom: -99999px; padding-bottom: 99999px` etc) but I didn't like it and I had some issues here and there with this, so I decided to use flex-box, I tried it some time ago with fixed size width and it worked fine but now I have percentage width so it seems that firefox didn't like it at all...

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/97dtV) example shows how I normally expected flex-box to work, and it did fine in safari and chrome, but firefox just ignore percentage width... I found that [it is a known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=529761) of firefox but it is an old one and I thought they solved it already...

Then I tried something [different](http://jsfiddle.net/97dtV/3) in order to trick firefox, but still it wasn't want I expected because sidebar had different size from page to page based on content...

So I end up by giving up on flex-box with fluid layout and use something more simple that fit my needs...

But I'm curious to know if anyone solve this issue with any workaround or if we are all in the queue for this to be fixed by mozila...

Thanks!

Comment: faux columns could be a solution? http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: it is almost the same hack as with margin/padding -bottom -/+ 99999px so you give a visual appearance that the columns have equal height but the in reality they don't, flexbox and table are true equal height technique, but the issue that I'm describing is not related with equal height column but with the fact that firefox ignores percentage width when is in flex box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly advise against using the `margin-bottom: -99999px; padding-bottom: 99999px` work-around.
If you want a fluid layout(I assume this is what the question is about?) with 14%, 86% split, just use plain old CSS instead of Flex.

http://jsfiddle.net/97dtV/7/

Why re-invent the wheel. If you are looking for a better way of laying out your site, try the "grid" approach.

- Semantic Grid (http://semantic.gs/)
- Bootstrap - (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html)

This assumes that you don't need flex for some specific reason, if you do then ignore this ;). Also, consider backward-compatibility when using CSS3 specific attributes!

Comment: the problem with the -/+99999px approach is that I need to have sidebar with `position:absolute` and this is something I need to avoid.

Comment: hmm I could have something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/97dtV/9/) though.. well to be honest I currently use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/97dtV/11/) approach and so far I'm happy with that... but thanks for you answer!

Comment: Plain old CSS [falls apart](http://jsfiddle.net/mlms13/97dtV/73/) as soon as your columns aren't the same height. Which is why people use the -/+9999px approach, or flexbox, or css tables. A semantic grid approach might be the best option, but it's a shame flexbox is so broken in Firefox.